# Set additional user to svn commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Before commit my code to repo someone review my code. I want to save information about that person in commit as 'reviewer'. Users who review code is same group of user who commit code.

Is svn or git support to save additional information to repo? Maybe some plugin ? I dont want to save that information in comment. I need additional field which will be required to commit.

Answer (score 0):

**Good news**

You can do it

**Bad news**

You can't do it in TortoiseSVN in nice GUI-way

**Details**

There are two types of properties in Subversion

- Versioned *properties for files and folders* inside repositories
- Unversioned *properties of revisions*

And TortoiseSVN's GUI and [property editors](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html) provide interface gor editing only 1-st type of properties (which you can use for your task, but with accuracy). Just sample of erroneous and inaccurate usage (from my dirty test)

In TortoiseSVN's GUI for `/trunk` I added property "Reviewer", enter some data (presumably correct) in property-editor and commit as revision 2

```
>svn pl file:///Z:/Repo/trunk -r 2 -v
Properties on 'file:///Z:/Repo/trunk':
  Reviewer
    Ann
```

Later some changes must be done additionally, and they become revision 3, which was committed (just as example) without code-review, but I forgot (or in order to don't show "No CR" - ignore) clean value of Reviewer or remove property and as result definitely wrong data stored in repo

```
>svn pl file:///Z:/Repo/trunk -v -r 3
Properties on 'file:///Z:/Repo/trunk':
  Reviewer
    Ann
```

property **versioned**, stored in **all** revisions in last-changed form

and mistake (or sabotage) was fixed only on revision, where real new Reviewer have to be noted

```
>svn pl file:///Z:/Repo/trunk -v -r 4
Properties on 'file:///Z:/Repo/trunk':
  Reviewer
    Sally
```

And, as additional note - these file|directory type properties are invisible in log

From other side, revision property related to just one revision, visible (with some headache) in logs, but haven't nice (and ugly - too) interface for setting it in TortoiseSVN and must be defined by hand at commit stage (option `--with-revprop` haveto be added to `svn ci ...`) - read [Properties page in SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html) and especially carefully "Searchability (or, Why Not Properties)" remark.

Anyway

```
>svn ci -m "Added details" --with-revprop "Reviewer=John"
Sending        A.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 5.
```

will return in log

```
>svn log --with-revprop Reviewer --xml -r 5
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="5">
<revprops>
<property
   name="Reviewer">John</property>
</revprops>
</logentry>
</log>
```

needed information (note mandatory options `--with-revprop` and `--xml`: `--with-revprop` doesn't work in plain-text mode) and "Reviewer" will be property only for this revision: for usual commit without `--with-revprop` none will be added|inherited

```
>svn log --with-revprop Reviewer --xml -r 6
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="6">
</logentry>
</log>
```

You still have search problem (because I can't get *any* results, using 1.8+ `--search`) with XML-logs